# What's wrong with my Dependency Property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The compiler and the runtime don't complain about the binding, but the Setter is never hit in my AutoCompleteTextBox.

```
<Controls:AutoCompleteTextBox   
    Items="{Binding Path=DropDownValues}"
    Width="200" 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Height="30"
   Tag="{Binding}"
  />
```

And

```
 public partial class AutoCompleteTextBox
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Items",
                typeof(ItemCollection),
                typeof(AutoCompleteTextBox),
                new PropertyMetadata(default(ItemCollection), OnItemsPropertyChanged));


       public ItemCollection Items
       {
           get
           {
               return (ItemCollection)GetValue(ItemsProperty);
           }
           set
           {
               SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); //doesn't get hit
           }
       }


//This is how i'm cheating since my Items is always null
        private void CanvasName_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            object obj = this.Tag;

            if (obj != null)
            {
                CjisQueryAutoCompleteData at = obj as CjisQueryAutoCompleteData;
                if (at != null)
                {
                    //use the data...
                    PopDropDown(at.DropDownValues);
                }
            }
        }

       //....
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

There's nothing wrong. When a dependency property is set in XAML, WPF directly accesses the DependencyProperty without calling the CLR wrapper. Think of it as if WPF would directly call SetValue.

See [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx), 
Implications for Custom Dependency Properties.

You will however notice that the property has been set when your `OnItemsPropertyChanged` callback is called.

Comment: Absolutely correct. That may seem weird to people at first, but once you consider that the XAML may not be setting an `ItemCollection`, but rather a `Binding` (if you are using data binding which is common with these types of properties), then it couldn't call the property because `Binding` does not inherit from `ItemCollection`.

Comment: @Brian Ball OnItemsPropertyChanged is not hit.  I found a workaround but it's pretty lame.  Let me know if you have any other ideas.

Comment: @patrickinmpls You should set the [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source.aspx) of your binding (or the [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) of the AutoCompleteTextBox) to the `CjisQueryAutoCompleteData` object (that you currently have in `Tag`).

Comment: @Clemens Items="{Binding Source=DropDownValues}" made no difference.  The AutoCompleteTextBox  DataContext is already a CjisQueryAutoCompleteData

Comment: @patrickinmpls When the DataContext contains a `CjisQueryAutoCompleteData`, and `DropDownValues` is a public property in `CjisQueryAutoCompleteData`, the correct binding expression is `{Binding Path=DropDownValues}`. Did you check the Visual Studio output window for possible binding errors?